# Duplicate code Command Class Java

Tags: java, command, code-duplication

I have this two classes that implements Command (using a command pattern), one is the create sheet:

```
public class CommandCreateSheet implements Command {

    private Workbook workbook;
    private String sheetName;

    public CommandCreateSheet(Workbook workbook, String workSheetName) {
        this.workbook = workbook;
        this.sheetName = workSheetName;
    }

    @Override
    public void execute() {
        this.workbook.addSheet(this.sheetName);
    }

    @Override
    public void undo() {
        this.workbook.removeSheet(this.sheetName);
    }
}
```

and the other is the delete:

```
public class CommandDeleteSheet implements Command {

    private Workbook workbook;
    private String sheetName;

    public CommandDeleteSheet(Workbook workbook, String workSheetName) {
        this.workbook = workbook;
        this.sheetName = workSheetName;
    }

    @Override
    public void execute() {
        this.workbook.removeSheet(this.sheetName);
    }

    @Override
    public void undo() {
        this.workbook.addSheet(this.sheetName);
    }
}
```

How can I avoid this duplicate code ?

Thanks!!

Comment: This code looks good to me.

Comment: You could avoid duplicate code by making an abstract super class with fields `workbook` and `sheetName`. It's probably only worth it if you need lots of subclasses.

Comment: It's hardly worth it for such small code. You'll still need the methods `execute` and `undo` to stay more or less the same, as they are class-specific, and you'll still need to declare the constructor (as constructors are not inherited), so it won't do you much good.

Comment: I create the AbstractCommand, it improve the solution, but I'm still getting duplicate code :S

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could create an intermediate abstract class that both commands implement.

```
public abstract class AbstactSheetCommand implements Command
{
    private Workbook workbook;
    private String sheetName;

    protected AbstractSheetCommand(Workbook workbook, String workSheetName)
    {
        this.workbook = workbook;
        this.sheetName = workSheetName;
    }

    public abstract void execute();
    public abstract void undo();
}
```

And then your subclasses would be much smaller:

```
public class CommandCreateSheet extends AbstractSheetCommand
{
    public CommandCreateSheet(Workbook workbook, String workSheetName)
    {
        super(workbook, workSheetName);
    }

    @Override
    public void execute() { this.workbook.addSheet(this.sheetName); }

    @Override
    public void undo() { this.workbook.removeSheet(this.sheetName);}
}

public class CommandDeleteSheet extends AbstractSheetCommand
{
    public CommandDeleteSheet(Workbook workbook, String workSheetName)
    {
        super(workbook, workSheetName);
    }

    @Override
    public void execute() { this.workbook.removeSheet(this.sheetName); }

    @Override
    public void undo() { this.workbook.addSheet(this.sheetName); }
}
```

The nice thing about doing it this way is that you can easily add new commands that are in the same "category" (so to speak) that have more specific functionality.

```
public class CommandRenameSheet extends AbstractSheetCommand
{
    private String newWorkSheetName;

    public CommandDeleteSheet(Workbook workbook, String oldWorkSheetName, String newWorkSheetName)
    {
        super(workbook, oldWorkSheetName);
        this.newWorkSheetName = newWorkSheetName;
    }

    @Override
    public void execute() 
    { this.workbook.renameSheet(this.sheetName, newWorkSheetName); }

    @Override
    public void undo() 
    { this.workbook.renameSheet(newWorkSheet, this.sheetName); }
}
```

Comment: Perfect, I also have a CommandSetCell class too, with same more attributes like the CommandRenameSheet you proposed.

Answer (score 1):

For such short code as yours, you save very little by trying to eliminate code, and the more code you save, the more complicated your solution will be.

But here is a possible Java 8 implementation using an abstract class.

```
public abstract class SheetCommand implements Command {

    private Runnable executeAction, undoAction;

    public SheetCommand(Runnable executeAction, Runnable undoAction) {
        this.executeAction = executeAction;
        this.undoAction = undoAction;
    }

    @Override
    public void execute() {
        executeAction.run();
    }

    @Override
    public void undo() {
        undoAction.run();
    }
}

public class CommandCreateSheet extends SheetCommand {

    public CommandCreateSheet(Workbook workbook, String workSheetName) {
        super(() -> workbook.addSheet(workSheetName),
              () -> workbook.removeSheet(workSheetName));
    }
}

public class CommandDeleteSheet extends SheetCommand {

    public CommandDeleteSheet(Workbook workbook, String workSheetName) {
        super(() -> workbook.removeSheet(workSheetName),
              () -> workbook.addSheet(workSheetName));
    }
}
```

This implementation uses lambda expressions to express the actions you need to do. Because lambda expressions are closures, you don't need to keep the actual workbook and sheet name references explicitly - they are hidden inside the lambda expressions.

For more complex code in the `execute` and `undo` you'll probably do better by writing the methods yourself as you originally did - if you try to do it with lambdas you'll end up with code that's more complex and unreadable than you originally had.

Comment: Plus one from me. Since `SheetCommand` doesn't have any abstract methods (that we know of), it might be slightly better to make it non-abstract and use static factories rather than subclasses.

Comment: @PaulBoddington Sorry about what happened, seems we were working in parallel. I was thinking about a non-abstract class, but I'm not sure if needing to change the head class (add a static method) every time we come up with a new command is really better. I suppose it depends on the situation.

Comment: It's my fault what happened. I posted a ridiculous answer holding duplicate references to the same objects. I agree, we don't have enough information to provide the perfect solution.

Comment: I think the solution posted by @Nik G would be fine. It's easier for my knowledge jaja. Thanks !